# How to deploy browserHistory based React applications to Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, iis, reactjs, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying a React app to an Azure App Service that uses non-hashed URLs (eg. browserHistory) like

```
http://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net/map/50.9375/6.9603/13
```

but that should all be handled by the same index.html for all paths.  How do you accomplish this in Azure App Service? Basically, i want all requests against the app service to map to /index.html and let React work it out.

Comment: Have you seen any progress in this issue. Would like to know the detailed process of deploying reactJS-redux(browserHistory too) app on azure. My backend is in azure functions. So I would like to deploy a static site react app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a web.config file in the root of your application that you deploy to Azure App Service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
       <rule name="redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
           <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
       </rule>
     </rules>
   </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```